Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) in build.gradle.kts if i use DS Photo Editor SDK Library
[  // DS Photo Editor SDK

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation(name:'ds-photo-editor-sdk-v10', ext:'aar')]



This file looks as if it's using the Groovy DSL rather than Kotlin. Try renaming it to build.gradle (leave out .kts) or rewrite it in Kotlin.
